# How do I run an interactive command line Python app inside of Emacs on Win32?

Tags: python, emacs

If I use M-x shell and run the interactive Python interpreter, Emacs on Windows does not return any IO.

When I discovered M-x python-shell, I regained hope.  However, instead of running the interactive Python shell, I want to run a specific Python script that features an interactive CLI.  (See Python's cmd module for details).

Is there a way of launching a Python script in Emacs that is interactive? (stdout, stdin, stderr)

Comment: Does the same problem exist with eshell or ansi-term?

Answer (score 2):

I grabbed one of the cmd examples from here: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cmd/index.html

Seemed like all the input lines in the example had a (Cmd) prompt - not sure if that's always the case.

Edited the python-shell definition in python.el to include "(Cmd) "

```
(setq comint-prompt-regexp "^>>> \\|^[.][.][.] \\|^(pdb) \\|^\\(Cmd\\) ")
```

re-evaluated the python-shell region, started the shell and loaded the script using:

>>> execfile("script.py")

Input/output seemed to work... not sure about stderr or if this would work with a more complicated script.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the other shell modes.  TERM-MODE and ANSI-MODE.  I believe they can support interactive command line programs.

Answer (score -1):

You can run python in interactive mode by typing python.exe -i 
Alternatively, you can download ipython and just run ipython.exe